# Problemas con algoritmo de recursividad (El resultado no es el esperado)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursión

Les escribo porque me encuentro presentando problemas con un ejercicio que consiste en crear un algoritmo que haga la conversión de un número entero a un número hexadecimal (base 16), con las siguientes reglas: Para residuos entre 10 y 15, se realiza la asignación 10='A',11='B',12='C',13='D',14='E' y 15='F'. Para los demás residuos, se le asigna el número (cifra) correspondiente. Me han pedido hacer este ejercicio con recursividad y sin recursividad. Pondre ambos ejercicios en la descripción, ahi explico paso a paso que es lo que hago, he hecho las con el número 8642 y, al parecer, esto sucede en el caso del algoritmo de recursividad: El resultado deberia de ser 21C2 y en esta algoritmo obtengo C122. Lo mismo pasa cuando introduzco el número 6583, obtengo B197 en vez del resultado correcto, que es 19B7. Me pudieran ayudar con esto por favor? Yo uso Python 3.8.8 en Windows 7.

En fin, he aquí mis códigos, y gracias de antemano por su pronta respuesta:

1a) Sin recursividad

```
def Asignacion(m):     #Con esta función, hago la debida asignación a cada resto que obtengo
     a=str()           # de dividir N entre 16 y sus cocientes respectivos
     if m==15:
          a='F'
     elif m==14:
          a='E'
     elif m==13:
          a='D'
     elif m==12:
          a='C'
     elif m==11:
          a='B'
     elif m==10:
          a='A'
     else:
          a=str(m)
     return a
def Invertir(a):
     StringInv=str()   #Creo una nueva variable StringInv que almacenara la variable 'a' 
                       #invertida
     n=len(a)          #Aqui considero el numero de caracteres de 'a'
     for k in range(n):    #k sera el indicador que recorrera a en sentido inverso 
          StringInv=StringInv+a[n-k-1]   #Como lo muestra esta linea(Recordar: 0<=k<=n-1) 
     return StringInv
def Conversion(N):
     a=str()             #'a' representará N convertido a hexadecimal. En principio es vacia
     while N>=16:
          m=N%16    
          N=N//16            
          #A continuacion, debo asignar a la variable 'a' segun el valor que tiene
          a=a+Asignacion(m)
     a=a+Asignacion(N)
     #Ahora, intercambiar el string revirtiendolo.
     a=Invertir(a)
     return a

print("Programa para convertir un número a hexadecimal")
n=int(input("Introduzca un numero entero a convertir:"))
print("El número "+str(n)+" en forma hexadecimal es:"+Conversion(n))
```

1b) Con Recursividad

```
def Asignacion(m):     # Con esta función, hago la debida asignacion de cada resto que obtengo
     b=str()           # de dividir el numero dado N entre 16. Como indica el ejercicio,
     if m==15:         # y 'b' es donde se almacenara la asignación (En principio está vacia)
          b='F'
     elif m==14:
          b='E'
     elif m==13:
          b='D'
     elif m==12:
          b='C'
     elif m==11:
          b='B'
     elif m==10:
          b='A'
     else:
          b=str(m)
     return b

def Invertir(a):    #Función que asigna a un string 'a', el mismo string 'a', pero invertido
     String=str()   #Creo una nueva variable llamada String que almacenará la variable 'a' 
                    #invertida
     n=len(a)       #Considero la cantidad de caracteres de 'a'
     for k in range(n):         #k va a recorrer el string 'a' pero en sentido inverso
          String=String+a[n-k-1]   #Como se muestra en esta linea
     return String
     
def Conversion(N):
     a=str()             #'a' represente N convertido a hexadecimal. En principio es vacia
     if 0<=N<=15:        # En este caso, ya representa un residuo y no hace falta operar mas
          a=Asignacion(N)    #Si N esta en ese rango, la función arroja el símbolo 
                              correspondiente a N(es el mismo N). 
     else:     #En este caso, N es mayor o igual a 16, entonces se le considera el resto, se  
               #se agrega a 'a' y ademas, la funcion del inicio aplicada al cociente entre N Y 
               #16, que es la base, y se vuelve a ejecutar la función para ese nuevo valor.
          a=a+Asignacion(N%16)+Conversion(N//16)    #Como se ve en esta linea
          a=Invertir(a)
     return a
         
print("Programa para convertir un número a hexadecimal")
n=int(input("Introduzca un numero entero a convertir:"))
print("El número "+str(n)+" en forma hexadecimal es:"+Conversion(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

El error está en estas líneas:

```
a=a+Asignacion(N%16)+Conversion(N//16) 
a=Invertir(a)
```

La forma correcta es:

```
a = a + Conversion(N // 16) + Asignacion(N % 16)
```

La idea es que vas a formar la respuesta uniendo la conversión del "digito" más significativo con la conversión del resto. En el original, el orden está invertido, lo que te desordena todo.

Demo

La función `Invertir` es innecesaria.

La función `Asignación` se puede reducir a una simple expresión que selecciona un caracter hexadecimal desde una cadena usando el valor como índice.

```
def Asignacion(m):  # Con esta función, hago la debida asignacion de cada resto que obtengo
    return "0123456789ABCDEF"[m]


def Conversion(N):
    a = str()  # 'a' represente N convertido a hexadecimal. En principio es vacia
    if 0 <= N <= 15:  # En este caso, ya representa un residuo y no hace falta operar mas
        a = Asignacion(N)  # Si N esta en ese rango, la función arroja el símbolo
    else:  # En este caso, N es mayor o igual a 16, entonces se le considera el resto, se
        # se agrega a 'a' y ademas, la funcion del inicio aplicada al cociente entre N Y
        # 16, que es la base, y se vuelve a ejecutar la función para ese nuevo valor.
        a = a + Conversion(N // 16) + Asignacion(N % 16)  # Como se ve en esta linea
    return a


print("Programa para convertir un número a hexadecimal")
n = int(input("Introduzca un numero entero a convertir:"))
print("El número " + str(n) + " en forma hexadecimal es:" + Conversion(n))
```

produce:

```
Programa para convertir un número a hexadecimal
Introduzca un numero entero a convertir:8642
El número 8642 en forma hexadecimal es:21C2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Por supuesto, eso hace innecesaria la Función Invertir. Lo hice sin acomodar la función Asignacion y me daba el mismo error que antes( O sea, cambiaba el orden entre Asignacion y Conversion, pero la función Asignacion tenia el mismo codigo). Y haciendo la modificación que me indicaste sobre la función Asignación, se me acomodo el código. No es por nada pero, podrias explicarme porque esto es asi? tiene que ver con que la recursión consume mucha memoria? Muchas gracias, de verdad.